# php using token inside form why token is importent

Tags: php, forms, token, access-token

I have some question about `access token` hope you guy's have the answer, I did my research but for sure I didn't understand why using `token` is so important to **secure** forms. So my question is and I hope to understand that what token exactly do in forms, how it's secure form and secure it from what. 
And is the token Important in login form but what if I didn't use the token inside login form is that make the form unsecured.

Comment: Sample of your code would be great to understand better what are you asking for.

Comment: i have no code i'm just asking why token is important

Comment: What you mean to secure forms? Are you talking about `access_token` given after login? I think `code` is more for securing forms if we are talking about oAuth.

Comment: when i did my research i found this article http://learnwebtutorials.com/using-random-form-token-to-help-protect-against-csrf and he's talking about why token is so Important in forms but he didn't say much

Comment: To protect you application from CSRF attacks https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard And example http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/csrf-attacks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access token is one of protection patterns against CSRF attack. CSRF stands for Cross-site Request Forgery. It is deeply explained here:
[WIKI-CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Forging_login_requests)

Especially take a look at Examples section and Prevention section.
In simple words this attack for example steals request with login information and lets intruder login in any time. If you have access token that is gone after session is gone or after opening the form another time, you are protected.
I encourage you to read the article above.

I hope this helped.